# Search files by pattern from console by user input - java

Tags: java, regex, file

I would like to ask you : How i can make a program which is making a simple "like filter" to search files by user input. Like when a user input from a console: 
 *fileName.txt it searches all files which is containing fileName and the asteriks shows that it can have some words before "fileName".

Here are some examples: 
User input from console:

*text.txt -> matches all files containing text.txt

fileName*.txt - > matches all files containing fileName and it can contains words after "fileName".
file*Name.txt ->matches all files containig file and Name and it can have some words between them.

I know it must be with regex , but i do not know what regex should i use. So can you tell me what patterns should i use .
Thank you in advanced!

Here is my code for now searching a files:

```
 public void FilterFile(String directory, String fileToSearch)
    {
 File filePath = null;
        if (directory != null)
        {

            File filePath = new File(directory); \\ reads Directory
            FilenameFilter fnf = new FilenameFilter()
            {

                @Override
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
                {
                    if (name != null)
                    {

                        if(pattern.matcher(name).matches()) // pattern that should use for matching and filtering files by user input
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    return false;
                }

            };

            File[] files = filePath.listFiles(fnf);

            if (files != null)
            {
                for (File file : files)
                {
                    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath() + " found");
                }
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: [`PathMatcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/PathMatcher.html) - it's already been written for you - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try

`(fileName)\w+.txt` 
for fileName*.txt

`(file)\w+(Name).txt` 
for   file*Name.txt

and

`\w+(text).txt` for *text.txt

Comment: but that is exactly the words that i said . I want to search all files that user input.

Comment: If you want any word - you replace fileName, file, name and text with `\w`